# python pandas converting dataframe(s) to lists

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have an excel with 2 data frames , one data frame on score card and other data frame on consolidation basis

```
import pandas as pd
df_scr_crd = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY'], 
        'SCR_STRT': [10, 20, 30, 99999, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
        'POINTS': [100, 200, 300, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40]}
df_scr_crd_d = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_crd, columns = ['Subject', 'SCR_STRT', 'POINTS'])

df_scr_cns = {'Subject': ['MATH', 'PSY'], 
        'CNS': ['min', 'max']}
df_scr_cns_d = pd.DataFrame(df_scr_cns, columns = ['Subject', 'CNS'])

df_scr_crd_d
df_scr_cns_d
```

I want to generate lists/variable assignments  from this data frame

The expected output is

```
MATH_df_scr_crd_bin = [10, 20, 30, 99999]
MATH_df_scr_crd_val = [100, 200, 300, 500]
PSY_df_scr_crd_bin = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
PSY_df_scr_crd_val = [10, 20, 30, 40]
MATH_df_scr_cns = 'min'
MATH_df_scr_cns = 'max'
```

Is there any easy way to convert a data frame to lists ?

Thx in advance
Vittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.tolist()` on the relevant series, e.g.:

```
>>> df_scr_crd_d.loc[df_scr_crd_d.Subject == 'MATH', 'SCR_STRT'].tolist()
[10, 20, 30, 99999]

>>> df_scr_crd_d.loc[df_scr_crd_d.Subject == 'MATH', 'POINTS'].tolist()
[100, 200, 300, 500]
```

For the whole dataframe, you can convert it to a dictionary keyed on the column names as follows:

```
>>> df_scr_crd_d.to_dict('list') 
{'POINTS': [100, 200, 300, 500, 10, 20, 30, 40],
 'SCR_STRT': [10, 20, 30, 99999, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 'Subject': ['MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'MATH', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY', 'PSY']}
```